# Is a Company Page forever linked to its creator on LinkedIn?

Tags: linkedin

Two of the [requirement to create a company page on LinkedIn](http://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1594/ft/eng), are

> 1) You must have a personal LinkedIn profile set up with your true first and last name.
>
> 4) You're a current company employee and your position is listed in the Experience section on your profile.

If I create the company page, will I be its "owner" forever? Will I be listed as its creator?

Or will I only be a regular administrator on the same level as any other administrator of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there will not be any creator on the page.

Look at this example: https://www.linkedin.com/company/teckhouse- where I'm not listed as creator.

Comment: Great! That is what I was hoping. So I guess that if I leave the company, any other administrator will be able to remove me as an administrator. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, it's true :)